# How do I redirect all unmatched urls with Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to redirect all unmatched urls to my homepage. Ie. someone goes to `www.mysite.com/blah/blah/blah/foo/bar` or `www.mysite.com/invalid_url` - I want to redirect them to `www.mysite.com`

Obviously I don't want to interfere with my valid urls.

So is there some wildcard matcher that I can use to redirect requests to these invalid urls?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can insert a 'catch all' middleware as last middleware/route in your Express chain:

```
//configure the order of operations for request handlers:
app.configure(function(){
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/assets'));  // try to serve static files
  app.use(app.router);                           // try to match req with a route
  app.use(redirectUnmatched);                    // redirect if nothing else sent a response
});

function redirectUnmatched(req, res) {
  res.redirect("http://www.mysite.com/");
}

...

// your routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) { ... });
...

// start listening
app.listen(3000);
```

I use such a setup to generate a custom `404 Not Found` page.

Comment: I know u know this rob but u might want to show the hierarchy in an express config so they get this in the right order. just a suggestion.

Comment: @C.Hazelton that's why I included the comments. Not clear enough? I'd be happy to add more :)

Comment: was saying as opposed to comments just a suggestion.

Comment: This answer is outdated and results in error, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37352454/node-js-app-configure-is-not-a-function). The other answer (using `app.all`) still works fine.

Comment: "app.configure() is no longer part of Express 4".  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37352454/node-js-app-configure-is-not-a-function/37352626#37352626

Comment: @rofrol fair enough :D

Answer (score 58):

Add a route at the end of the rest of your routes.

```
app.all('*', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect("http://www.mysite.com/");
});
```

Comment: I didn't know you can use "all". Good answer.

Comment: If you add such a route, any middleware that you'd want to use after your routes, like `express.static`, will never be called, even if you include the `app.all` after that middleware declaration ([gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/5608473)). Might not be an issue, but it can be confusing.

Answer (score 3):

I'm super early here but this is my solution to this

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index')
})

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/')
})
```

Just uses the order of routes to redirect 1 specific url before it has a catch-all route for everything else. You can put whatever route you want to have above the catch-all and you'll be good to go.

My example just redirects and url given to the same root page