# Express middleware calls multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware, express-router

I've checked other posts related to this topic and couldn't find the problem in my code.

```
const myMiddleware = (fn) => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.url;
        console.log(fullUrl)
        next()
    }
}

const app = express()

app.use('/dist', express.static(__dirname + '/client/dist'))
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/client/static'))

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(cookieParserMiddleware())
app.use(passport.initialize())

const server = https.createServer(options, app)

app.get('/', myMiddleware((req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/dist/index.html')
}))

app.all('*', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/')
})

server.listen(8080, function listening() {
    console.log('Listening on %d', server.address().port)
})
```

Without the `myMiddleware` on `'/'` path everything works as expected. With `myMiddleware` attached as `app.get('/', myMiddleware((req, res) => {` then `myMiddleware` is called multiple times without `res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/dist/index.html')` being called.

---

EDIT: The bug below is fixed with jfriend00's solution. The middleware getting called multiple times still exists. The reason is favicon and some other assets are not being captured by `app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/client/static'))` line. Fixing path solved the first bug as well

On top of that problem, I've tried removing the part below but then the app doesn't work at all. My guess is there are 2 bugs here.

```
app.all('*', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/')
})
```

I have posted an image on how it looks when removing `app.all('*'..)`

[image]

Comment: Your middleware is not written correctly.  I don't know what you're trying to do with it, but the callback you pass to it is never used.  All it ever does is call `next()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Normally there is code written inside but to figure out what's wrong I have simplified it for testing. You can assume it has console.log() or some other logic inside

Comment: Do you realize that `app.get('/', myMiddleware((req, res) => {...});` never does anything?  All it does is call `next()`.  That's my point.  I don't know what you intended it to do, but it serves no purpose in your code example.  I can't tell what your question really is so  I don't know if this is related to the question or not. So, all your code does is redirect to `/` which redirects to `/` which redirects to `/` and so on.  It never does anything else, but an infinite loop until the browser probably detects too many redirects.

Comment: **Imagine** it does something. I edited the code to print url just for your sake. Without the middleware there is no redirection loop and the app works. WIth **any** middleware there is redirection loop.

Comment: You need a route that does SOMETHING other than redirect.  You don't show one.  So, all your server does is redirect over and over.  If you can't get that or show us more of your real code, then I'll move on.

Comment: You are talking about `app.all('*')` not `'/'`. `'*'` does something which redirects all other links to home. It's a single page app. The line enforces this behavior. I didn't get why the posted error in the image happens when removing `app.all('*')` which might be another issue on top of the redirect loop

Comment: From the code you show `res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/dist/index.html')` is NEVER called.  So, every single request that isn't satisfied by an `express.static()` route ends up in your `app.all('*', ...)` and redirects which will then just redirect and so on.

Comment: `res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/dist/index.html')` is called when I delete the middleware. Could you explain why there is this behaviour.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16637468/4335588

Comment: "delete the middleware" isn't very specific.  You have at least 6 lines of middleware.  I give up.  Hopefully someone else will come along and try to understand the question.

Comment: I'll make it clearer. I was talking about `myMiddleware`

Comment: Yeah, that's because `myMiddleware` NEVER calls the `fn` you pass it.  That's the point I made in my very first comment.  There is no `fn()` anywhere to ever call that in your implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to make a guess here.

Change this:

```
app.get('/', myMiddleware((req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/dist/index.html')
}));
```

to this:

```
app.get('/', myMiddleware(), (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/dist/index.html')
}));
```

So that your `res.sendFile()` actually gets called after the `myMiddleware` calls `next()`.

---

Then, remove the `fn` argument so you have this (doesn't change execution, but removes misleading and unused argument):

```
const myMiddleware = () => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.url;
        console.log(fullUrl)
        next()
    }
}
```

Comment: I mentioned there were two bugs. (1) multiple calls to middleware (2) deleting `app.all('*', (req, res) => {` would cause errors. With your changes applied we've This fixed bug #2, but, calling localhost:8080 would call `myMiddleware` 3 times

Comment: @Thellimist - That's not surprising.  One call to your server will be for the favicon. 
 Do you have any `<img>` `<script>` tags or other resource references in your HTML page to make other calls to your server.  You are logging the URL in your middleware.  You can see what is being requested, right?

Comment: I have `static/css/lobby.css` and `static/css/style.css` and favicon. Is it normal for them to call or is there a better way?

Comment: @Thellimist - That's how the browser gets those files.  It makes a request back to your server for each one.  That's how web pages work.

Comment: they are calling the `static/`  path so I assumed the `express.static` middleware would catch that request and not pass it all the way to `myMiddleware`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Thellimist - If those requests are getting past your `express.static()` middleware, then that middleware isn't matching them properly.  Either they aren't configured correctly or the URLs you're asking for aren't right.  We can't do anything here about that without knowing both the URLs that are being request and seeing exactly where the desired matching files are in your file system.  It's a very common mistake to specific `express.static()` stuff incorrectly.